# Should I capitalize the cardinal direction in phrases like 'western Chicago' and 'northern Sumatra'?

Tags: capitalization

To the best of my knowledge, we should capitalize cardinal directions in phrases that refer to a region commonly referred to by that phrase; for example: *Eastern Europe* and *Western Hemisphere*.

However, I don't know whether we should capitalize cardinal directions in spontaneously constructed phrases that refer to a region; for example: *western Chicago* and *northern Sumatra*. Should the cardinal directions in these phrases be capitalized?

Comment: I think it is a duplicate.  The answer is basically "If it's an existing proper noun, capitalize, otherwise don't"

Comment: Of related interest: *[How should “Northern Europe” be capitalized?](/questions/164045)*, *[East Coast, East coast, or east coast?](/questions/242399)*, and *[Should the cardinal directions be capitalized when used as an adjective?](/questions/341426)*, among others.